# How can I write to the next line in a text file?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

How can I make sure that the message I'm writing is on a blank line and doesn't write over more text? Does it involve reading the file first? Here is my code so far.

```
 Console.WriteLine("What do you wish to write?");
 String input2 = Console.ReadLine();
 Console.WriteLine("What file do you wish to write to?");
 fpath = Console.ReadLine();
 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(fpath));
 sw.WriteLine(input2);
 sw.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`StreamWriter` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) has an overload with a second parameter that indicates whether you want to append to the file. Also, this constructor accepts a path, so you don't need to use `File.OpenWrite`.

```
using( StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fpath, true) )
{
    sw.WriteLine(input2);
}
```